# Bootstrap carousel space issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm developing a web page with the help of bootstrap and i have carousel area this carousel works quite good but whenever i added hidden-xs class to my carousel area slider disappears ok.But height of carousel area protect itself i mean if my carousel area 500px height when slider hidden in mobile slider disappear but 500px space is not dissappear ?

my-codes below;

```
<!--carousel area/slider alanı-->
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide slider-area hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="sliders/temsili_1.jpg" alt="Aurum otelleri slider açıklaması">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="sliders/temsili_2.jpg" alt="Aurum otelleri slider açıklaması">
        </div>
      </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--carousel area/slider alanı-bitti-->
```

could you help me ?

Comment: can you put any demo. How will anyone come to know your issue?

Comment: @yedincifirat give the `hidden-XS` parent of the carousel

Comment: it's already added parent :)

Comment: can you add more of your code here?  like the parent div of your carousel?

Comment: @locateganesh here you are dude;
http://content.anitur.com.tr/ftp-grafik/stackoverflow/

Comment: pretty neat website and i think it is actually hidden, the space below is due to the position of your main title.. you might want to vertically align on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the website link which is: [your website](http://content.anitur.com.tr/ftp-grafik/stackoverflow/). Tested it on mobile. The div is actually hidden and the space is due to the main title alignment which I suggest you vertically align on mobile devices using the media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /*insert some styling here. you know how it is done :)*/
}
```

For vertical alignment of text in div you can refer to this [Vertical align text in div - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div). The explanation and answers are pretty good.

Bootstrap widths are defined like this:

- Extra small devices < 768px
- Small devices >= 768px
- Medium devices >= 992px
- Large devices: >=1200px